# IAM Policy to list specific folders inside a S3 bucket for an user

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I have below keys under  the bucket **demo.for.customers**

```
demo.for.customers/customer1/
demo.for.customers/customer2/
```

Now I have 2 customers namely **customer1** and **customer2**. This is what I want:

1. Grant them access to only **demo.for.customers** bucket.
2. customer1 should be able to access only `demo.for.customers/customer1/` and customer2 should be able to access only `demo.for.customers/customer2/`.

And I am able to achieve this with below policy ( I am creating policy for each customer. Hence I am pasting the one only for customer1 below.) I have defined this policy in IAM and not in S3.

```
{
 "Version":"2012-10-17",
 "Statement": [
   {
     "Action": ["s3:ListAllMyBuckets", "s3:GetBucketLocation"],
     "Effect": "Allow",
     "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::*"]
   },
   {
      "Action": ["s3:ListBucket"],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::demo.for.customers"],
      "Condition":{"StringEquals":{"s3:prefix":["","customer1/"],"s3:delimiter":["/"]}}
   },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": ["s3:*"],
      "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::demo.for.customers/customer1/*"]
    }
]
}
```

**Problem:**

1. Customer1 is able to see all my bucket although he can't access any of them . I don't want this. He should be able to see only **demo.for.customers**
2. Customer1 is able to see `demo.for.customers/customer2` as well although he can't access it. THis is highly unacceptable as I don't want him to even see what other customer folders I have under this bucket.

**QUESTIONS:**

1. After doing a lot of googling, I came to know that there is no way to **list specific buckets**. Is this really true?
2. However, I have to find a way to **list only specific folders** inside a bucket for a given user. How to do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your problems:

1. Unfortunately there is no way to list only certain buckets. If the intent is just to allow access to the one known bucket, I would remove the first statement entirely as it does not add any value (the bucket is already known and would not need to be listed).
2. Can you show the code you are using to list the bucket contents? Based on what you've shown here I would expect customer1 to only be able to list the bucket contents at the root of their prefix and nowhere else.

Regarding your questions:

1. Yes, there is no way to list certain buckets. The list buckets API is an all or nothing operation.
2. This is done by prefix. What language are you using? We have a sample for the AWS Mobile SDKs that uses a Token Vending Machine to deliver [per user access to an S3 bucket](http://aws.amazon.com/code/4598681430241367).

Comment: +1 for your time. I am using `aws s3 ls s3://demo.for.customers` and `aws s3api list-objects --bucket demo.for.customers` commands to do my testing. As well as, I am checking via console too and running a simple ruby script which uses AWS ruby SDK. I am expecting my customer to have console access and hence I am extremely concerned about **listing** of the folders inside a bucket. I don't want any customer so even **see** what other folders are there in the bucket.

Comment: Is there a particular reason your users need console access? That does complicate matters a bit.

Comment: Yes. My customers will be uploading auxiliary data in S3. And They are not the Tech-savvy people. Hence, I don't want them to get into the hassles of using S3 APIs for doing the same. In fact, they just want to get the data to me via easiest possible way.

Comment: Unfortunately the console does not support this level of fine-grained access control.  You can definitely prevent them from viewing or uploading to a bucket or prefix/folder, but not from seeing them entirely.  If you desire this functionality you would need to implement your own system to upload to S3 via a web app in order to hide the other customer folders or buckets from view.

Comment: Yes. That was my hunch too. I will be opening a ticket with AWS and will post the information here in case they have a workaround or something. Thanks.

Comment: @slayedbylucifer Did you get a workaround for your problem?

Comment: @BobKinney Do these limitation still exist? Can the requirement in the question be achieved as of today ?

Comment: @auhuman to the best of my knowledge, nothing has changed and these restrictions still apply.