# Provide folder access to single customer

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

In S3 I have a bucket called `customerdata`.  Under this, I want to have folders for each customer, so

```
/customerdata/bobjones/project1/data
/customerdata/jamessmith/project1/data
```

I need to provide each customer access ONLY to their folder and the data in it, preferably with a simple free tool like cloudberry s3 explorer.  The goal is to have Bob Jones login to cloudberry, and see the data in the `bobjones` folder.

So far though, I have only been able to show Bob everything in the bucket, or nothing.  Here's the policy I tried to set up, following [this article](http://blogs.aws.amazon.com/security/post/Tx1P2T3LFXXCNB5/Writing-IAM-policies-Grant-access-to-user-specific-folders-in-an-Amazon-S3-bucke), [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20040992/iam-policy-to-list-specific-folders-inside-a-s3-bucket-for-an-user), and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25559975/aws-restricting-iam-user-to-specific-folder-in-s3-bucket):

```
{
 "Version":"2012-10-17",
 "Statement": [
   {
     "Sid": "AllowUserToSeeBucketListInTheConsole",
     "Action": ["s3:ListAllMyBuckets", "s3:GetBucketLocation"],
     "Effect": "Allow",
     "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::*"],
     "Condition":{"StringEquals":{"s3:prefix":["","customerdata/"],"s3:delimiter":["/"]}}
   },
  {
     "Sid": "AllowRootAndHomeListingOfCompanyBucket",
     "Action": ["s3:ListBucket"],
     "Effect": "Allow",
     "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::customerdata"],
     "Condition":{"StringEquals":{"s3:prefix":["","bobjones/"],"s3:delimiter":["/"]}}
    },
   {
     "Sid": "AllowListingOfUserFolder",
     "Action": ["s3:ListBucket"],
     "Effect": "Allow",
     "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::customerdata"],
     "Condition":{"StringLike":{"s3:prefix":["bobjones/*"]}}
   },
   {
     "Sid": "AllowAllS3ActionsInUserFolder",
     "Effect": "Allow",
     "Action": ["s3:*"],
     "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::customerdata/bobjones/*"]
   }
 ]
}
```

What am I doing wrong?  Is this even possible what I'm trying to do?  I also tried the group first approach and saw nothing in cloudberry.

If this isn't the right approach, what is the correct way to set this up so that each customer sees ONLY their projects and data?

Answer (score 0):

It may be simpler to do this using the `${aws:username}` IAM policy variable, as described here:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/PolicyVariables.html

But mind that this would be for IAM users, not suitable for application users.